# Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate' and another error

Tags: swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var tasks = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.title = "Tasks"
         
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        if !UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "setup"){
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "setup")
            UserDefaults().set(0, forKey: "count")
            
        }
        
        updateTasks()
        
    }
    
    func updateTasks() {
        tasks.removeAll()
        
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else{
            return
            
        }
        
        for x in 0 ..< count {
            
            if  let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String {
                tasks.append(task)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    @IBAction func didTapAdd() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "entry")  as! EntryViewController
        vc.title = "New Task"
        vc.update = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateTasks()
                
            }
            
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {  //error:Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tasks") as! TaskViewController
        vc.title = "New Tasks"
        vc.task = tasks(indexPath.row) //errors:Cannot call value of non-function type '[String]'
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        
    }
        
      }
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {   //error:Redundant conformance of 'ViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: class ViewController : UIViewController instead class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using viewController and will adapt it to `tableViewDelegate` & `DataSource` Then the below will work but if you are using `tableViewController` you will need to remove the extension, you don't need it, and regarding the tableView functions you can create them in your `ViewContoller`

```
import UIKit
class ViewController : UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var tasks = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.title = "Tasks"
     
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    if !UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "setup"){
        UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "setup")
        UserDefaults().set(0, forKey: "count")
        
    }
    
    updateTasks()
    
}

func updateTasks() {
    tasks.removeAll()
    
    guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else{
        return
        
    }
    
    for x in 0 ..< count {
        
        if  let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String {
            tasks.append(task)
            
        }
        
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       tableView.reloadData()

     }
    
}

@IBAction func didTapAdd() {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "entry")  as! EntryViewController
    vc.title = "New Task"
    vc.update = {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.updateTasks()
            
        }
        
    }
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
} 

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tasks") as! TaskViewController
    vc.title = "New Tasks"
    vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row] 
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    
}
    
  }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return tasks.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first declaration of the `View Controller` class, you have created it to conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. To fix the code, remove `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` from the class declaration.

In conclusion, **just make your second line of code** `class ViewController : UIViewController{`

**Also, replace** `vc.task = tasks(indexPath.row)` with `vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row]` because when accessing array elements, you use brackets (`[]`), not parenthesis.

Comment: @le khoile if there is a correct answer posted, either mine or the other answer, please accept it to show its validity.